# makePersistent is appending elements to my list instead of replacing the list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, composition

I'm using the GAE datastore with JDO to hold course information.  Each Course has a List of GradeDefinition objects (e.g. "A=90%+", "B=80%+", etc)

When I try to change the List, the new elements are simply appended behind the old elements.  I suspect there is a problem with the way I am using detachable objects and persistence managers.

A basic rundown:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Course
{
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private GradingPolicy gradingPolicy;
}

@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class GradingPolicy
{
    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    private List<GradeDefinition> gradeDefinitions;
}

@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class GradeDefinition
{
    @Persistent
    private String gradeName; //e.g. "A", "B", etc.
}
```

Then, when I want to update the list of GradeDefinition objects in a Course, I:

1. Get the course object (which automatically fetches its GradingPolicy, which automatically fetches its list of GradeDefinition objects),
2. Prepare my new list of GradeDefinitions with

   `List<GradeDefinition> newDefinitions = new ArrayList<GradeDefinitions>();
   newDefinitions.add(new GradeDefinition("X")); //for example
   newDefinitions.add(new GradeDefinition("Y"));`
3. Reset the list by calling `course.getGradingPolicy.setGradeDefinitions(newDefinitions);`
4. Persist the changes by calling `persistenceManager.makePersistent(course);`

But, if the grading policy originally had A, B, and C in it, it now holds A, B, C, X, and Y!

Is there something I need to do to clear the list?  Do I need to manually delete the old GradeDefinitions?

Comment: This was indeed a problem with detachable entities and multiple persistence managers.  I solved it by doing all data operations within the lifespan of a single persistence manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out for inconsistencies between multiple PersistanceManagers, or even better, only have a single PersistanceManager floating around at a time.